# Load images into a Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-delayed

I have a dask dataframe which contains image paths in a column (called img_paths). What I want to do in the next steps is to load images using those image paths into an another column (called `img_loaded`) and followed by applying some pre-processing functions.

However, during loading (or, image reading) process I am always getting different results including one time delayed wrapping of the imread function, another time correct loading of the image (I can see the arrays) and rest of the times: `FileNotFoundError`.

In addition to the following examples, I have used `map_partitions` function as well but I am also ended up in similar outputs except without having the arrays. In the end, I want to use `map_partitions` function than `apply` function.

Following is my code and descriptions about the problems:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from skimage.io import imread

imgs = ['https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a'] * 42

# create a pandas dataframe using image paths
df = pd.DataFrame({"img_paths": imgs})

# convert it into dask dataframe
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# convert imread function as delayed
delayed_imread = dask.delayed(imread, pure=True)
```

#### First try: using lambda function and apply delayed `imread` to each cell

```
ddf["img_loaded"] = ddf.images.apply(lambda x: delayed_imread(x))
ddf.compute()
```

Here what I get is wrapping of the delayed `imread` function when using the `compute()` method. I do not understand why? Following is the output:

[image]

#### Second try: without using lambda function

```py
ddf["img_loaded"] = ddf.images.apply(delayed_imread)
ddf.compute()
```

This has worked! At least, I can see the loaded images as the arrays. But, I really do not get it why? why is this different than the first solution (i.e., using lambda function) Following is the output:

[image]

#### Third try: with/without using lambda function and without using delayed `imread`.

```py
ddf["load"] = ddf.images.apply(imread) # or, lambda x: imread(x)
ddf.compute()
```

Here, again just for an experimentation I did not use the delayed `imread` function, rather I use simply the `skimage.io.imread` function. And, I have tried both using with and without lambda function. In each time, I got **`FileNotFoundError`**. I did not get this. Why can't it find the image path (although, they are correct) when using non-delayed imread function?

### In addition to Ronald's answer, how to use map_partitions function:

```py
ddf["img_loaded"] = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.images.apply(lambda x: imread(x)), meta=("images", np.uint8)).compute()
ddf.compute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

imgs = ['https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a'] * 4

# create a pandas dataframe using image paths
df = pd.DataFrame({"img_paths": imgs})

# convert it into dask dataframe
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# convert imread function as delayed
delayed_imread = dask.delayed(imread, pure=True)

# give dask information about the function output type
ddf['img_paths'].apply(imread, meta=('img_loaded', np.uint8)).compute()

# OR turn it into dask.dealayed, which infers output type `object`
ddf['img_paths'].apply(delayed_imread).compute()
```

### The explanation

If you do try applying the `print` function, without computation you see the reason for `FileNotFoundError` of code: `ddf.images.apply(imread).compute()`

```py
ddf['img_paths'].apply(print)
```

Output:

```sh
> foo
> foo
```

When you add `apply` function to the graph, Dask runs through it string `foo` to infer the type of the output => `imread` was trying to open file named `foo`.

To get a better understanding I encourage you to try:

```py
ddf.apply(print, axis=1)
```

And try to predict what gets printed.

#### Delayed cells after `.compute()`

The reason is `apply` expects a function reference which is then called. By creating lambda function calling the delayed function you are basically double-delaying your function.