# MemoryError when trying to normalize an array of images

Tags: python, image, numpy, dataset, normalize

I have a folder containing 110k images with shape (256, 256, 3) each. I'm reading one by one, converting to a numpy array and storing in a list. After that, I convert the list to a numpy array. The shape of the numpy array is (110000, 256, 256, 3). Then, when I try to normalize the images with **images = images / float(255)**, this error is displayed:

```
 File "loading_images.py", line 25, in <module>
    images = images / float(255)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 161. GiB for an array with shape (110000, 256, 256, 3) and data type float64
```

Is there any other way to do that?

My current code is this:

```
files = glob.glob(dir + "*.png")
images = []
for f in files
    im = cv2.imread(f)
    img_arr = np.asarray(im)
    images.append(img_arr)

images = np.asarray(images)
images = images / float(255)
```

Comment: You could use dask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620786/load-images-into-a-dask-dataframe . The interesting thing with Dask is that you can load large amount of data, and actually read the values only when you need them!

Comment: Thank you! I search and found ImageDataGenerator from keras. It can load large amount of data and normalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think your issue is that cv2 gives an int8 (correct me if I'm wrong), and you're trying to cast the values into float64's

```
import numpy as np 
print(np.float64(255).itemsize)
print(np.int8(255).itemsize)
```

Which means that after the typecast, you're left with approximately 8 times the bytes. you have 110000×256×256×3=21GB of image data to begin with, which is probably just within your RAM limitation. After the conversion to float, you get 8x21 = 168GB of data, which is above the RAM limit of anyone I know haha.

This is no solution however, do you really need to load all the images at the same time?

Comment: I think I do, cause I'm trying to use them as input to ResNet-50. 

```(test_im, test_lab) = load_test_images(path_test_images)
    (train_im, train_lab) = load_train_images(path_train_images)
```

Comment: Hmm that's a pity, I don't have any experience with that, but can't imagine they require floating-point numbers as input only, are you sure you cant just load images described by integers? Any image library I've used so far just uses good old integers :P Does ResNet-50 take files as input by any chance? then you might sequentially save the images as floating point arrays maybe.